# Finding a particular zip file name from a folder and then unzip (extract) that file in a given location

Tags: vbscript, unzip

I wrote the following code in VBScript to first extract name of zip file and then to extract the same file in a given folder, but I am getting an error.

```
strFolder = "C:\Users\Desktop\tf\"

Dim aFileNameSize(0)

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set colFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolder)
Set colFiles = colFolder.Files

For Each strFile In colFiles
   aFileNameSize(0) = strfile.Name
   strFileName = aFileNameSize(0)
Next

'The location of the zip file.
ZipFile = "C:\Users\Desktop\tf\strFileName"

'The folder the contents should be extracted to.
ExtractTo = "C:\Users\Desktop\tf\UNZIP\"

'If the extraction location does not exist create it.
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If Not fso.FolderExists(ExtractTo) Then
    fso.CreateFolder(ExtractTo)
End If

'Extract the contants of the zip file.
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set FilesInZip = objShell.NameSpace(ZipFile).Items

objShell.NameSpace(ExtractTo).CopyHere(FilesInZip)

Set fso = Nothing
Set objShell = Nothing
```

It is throwing an error saying

> Object required: objshell.NameSpace(--)

Note: I wrote individual code for unzip and extracting the name and it's working perfectly fine.

Comment: `ZipFile = "C:\Users\Desktop\tf\strFileName"` -> `ZipFile = objFSO.BuildPath("C:\Users\Desktop\tf", strFileName)`

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers how is that a duplicate?  The issue is not with calling VBScript with Args

Comment: Both users are trying to use a variable *INSIDE A STRING*.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Still getting a syntax error with -> ZipFile=

Comment: Teaching you the basics of VBScript syntax is beyond the scope of SO. Please go find a VBScript tutorial. No, I don't know any I could recommend, and recommendations are off-topic anyway.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Hi Ansgar. I am really sorry to disappoint you. Though i fixed that problem. Thanks a ton for your kind help:)